# Asynchronous HTTP request and bootstrap-multiselect

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, bootstrap-4, xmlhttprequest

I've been stuck on a problem that I'm having for most of the day today. I'm using js to make a dynamic table populated from a database. As part of this table, I'm using the [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) to make dropdown menus for filtering in a couple of the columns. I'm making an asynchronous call in my javascript to get the values for the dropdown from my database which works - it gets the values I'm looking for. But it seems like the response and generation of that element is coming after the multiselect script gets fired. From what I understand, I can't defer the script since it doesn't reference an external file, and I'm not sure how to put the script that makes the multiselect element into the script which makes the table. I've kind of narrowed it down to being an issue with async request/server response time because the problem is intermittent and the select gets populated with the options every time, but multiselect script is supposed to create a series of checkboxes with the values - the empty list is suggesting that the options hadn't been populated when the script was executed.

```
SCRIPT IN HTML
<script src = "js/shows.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selectBand').multiselect();
        $('#selectVenue').multiselect();
      });
</script>
```

```
JAVASCRIPT FOR POPULATING TABLE (abridged js/shows.js)

function loadFilter(filter){
var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (filter == 'Band'){
    req.open('GET', 'myserver/getBands', true);
      req.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400){
    var bandFilter = document.getElementById('selectBand');
    var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    for (i in data.rows){
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value=Object.values(data.rows[i]);
      option.innerHTML=Object.values(data.rows[i]);
      bandFilter.appendChild(option);
      // console.log(data);
    }
  }
  })
  req.send(null);
}
```

Do any of you have any suggestions on how to get these separate scripts to execute at the right times? I chopped up my js for a while thinking I could fix it with a mess of callbacks and async functions but kept ending with the same issue.
Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to use `.multiselect('rebuild')` to get your multiselect widget updated in the `load` event handler.

Comment: Cool, that's one of the things I was thinking about but wasn't really sure how to make it work. I tried $('#selectBand').multiselect('rebuild'); in the script in my html file but that didn't work. Are you saying to put it in window.onload() of the js file?

Comment: I think it would go right after the `for` loop in the `XMLHttpRequest` `load` handler.